# pc directly booting into Ubuntu after dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I had win 8.1 x64 earlier, now I installed Ubuntu 14.04 lts alongside windows but I am unable to boot into windows. Need some urgent help

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/706816/dual-boot-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-windows-10-on-acer-aspire-e-15/706823#706823

Comment: Maybe you can try ```https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair```

Comment: @TungTran That's needed for installation. Disabling Fast Boot has NOTHING to do with GRUB. You should use Boot-Repair... in a Ubuntu Live (x). Also, do you even think he can boot to Windows 10 when he only CAN BOOT TO UBUNTU?

Answer (score 1):

I think GRUB is not working in your system.
Make sure you installed Windows first, then Ubuntu, leaving a linux-swap partition available.
If GRUB doesn't open for you, try repeatedly pressing Esc when booting, then you should get the GRUB menu and see your Windows partition there. If GRUB doesn't open yet, then hold Shift while booting to get GRUB.
If your issue is that Windows does not appear on GRUB, please inform it.

Answer (score 0):

Check BIOS settings usually F2 or F12 when booting computer. Make sure that fast boot and secure boot is turned off. (may be called something else for your manufacture) Boot into Ubuntu in a terminal type `sudo update-grub` then update `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get upgrade` Remove all old packages `sudo apt-get autoremove` Then reboot the computer `sudo reboot`